# How do I make a link to a section of a document in the same directory(pandoc markdown->html output)

Tags: html, documentation, hyperlink, markdown, pandoc

I have two fairly simple pieces of documentation(written in markdown that is used to generate html files with pandoc). I'd like to be able to link to a section of the second document from the first document.

Preference order for solutions:

- Using General Markdown Features
- Using Pandoc Extensions Using
- embedded HTML

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pandoc has a "[Header identifiers in HTML](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#header-identifiers-in-html-latex-and-context)"-extension for this usecase. In the documentation is an example, how to provide links from one section of a document to another.

Comment: yay I just did a [link-to-section](./docname.html/#lowercasesectionname) and it worked.

Comment: `[Section Name](#lowercasesectionname)` also works