# Internal section link fails in beamer output of pandoc markdown

Tags: pandoc, beamer

I have tried the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8961208/704028), but I can't get the internal section links in [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to work with the [Latex Beamer](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/tex/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) output.

Following the [Pandoc Documentation](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#header-identifiers-in-html-latex-and-context), I have created this minimal working example:

```
# Part One {#part-one}

## Section One {#section-one} 

### Frame one {#frame-one}

- Items... 

### Frame two {#frame-two}

- Items... 
- Link to [Section One](#section-one)
```

And built it using:

```
pandoc \
    --table-of-contents \
    -s -t beamer test.md \
    -o test.pdf
```

The built LaTex Beamer pdf looks fine, but the internal link `[Section One](#section-one)` just isn't working. It should bring me to the "Section One" frame but it doesn't. How do I make this work?

Edit: here is the LaTex output for `-o test.latex`:

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\setbeamertemplate{caption label separator}{:}
\setbeamercolor{caption name}{fg=normal text.fg}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} % provides \textsubscript
\usepackage{lmodern}
\ifxetex
  \usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
  \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
  \newcommand{\euro}{€}
\else
  \ifluatex
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text,Scale=MatchLowercase}
    \newcommand{\euro}{€}
  \else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
      \fi
\fi
% use upquote if available, for straight quotes in verbatim environments
\IfFileExists{upquote.sty}{\usepackage{upquote}}{}
% use microtype if available
\IfFileExists{microtype.sty}{\usepackage{microtype}}{}

% Comment these out if you don't want a slide with just the
% part/section/subsection/subsubsection title:
\AtBeginPart{
  \let\insertpartnumber\relax
  \let\partname\relax
  \frame{\partpage}
}
\AtBeginSection{
  \let\insertsectionnumber\relax
  \let\sectionname\relax
  \frame{\sectionpage}
}
\AtBeginSubsection{
  \let\insertsubsectionnumber\relax
  \let\subsectionname\relax
  \frame{\subsectionpage}
}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{6pt plus 2pt minus 1pt}
\setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}  % prevent overfull lines
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}

\date{}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]
\end{frame}

\part{Part One}\label{part-one}

\hyperdef{}{section-one}{\section{Section One}\label{section-one}}

\begin{frame}{Frame one}

\begin{itemize}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item
  Items\ldots{}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame two}

\begin{itemize}
\itemsep1pt\parskip0pt\parsep0pt
\item
  Items\ldots{}
\item
  Link to \hyperref[section-one]{Section One}
\end{itemize}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: works for me, what pandoc version are you using? Also, try `-s -t beamer -o test.tex` to see whether the generated .tex is fine.

Comment: pandoc 1.13.1
Compiled with texmath 0.8, highlighting-kate 0.5.11.

Comment: I've added the latex output.... it uses hyperref to 'part-one' (I am trying things out so the link is different), but I can't click on it in pdf...

Answer (score 2):

I think I've pinpointed it to the `ignorenonframetext` in `\documentclass[ignorenonframetext,]{beamer}`, which is part of the default Pandoc beamer template.

Since the `\hyperdef{}{part-one}{\section{Part One}\label{part-one}}` is not inside a `frame`, it is apparently ignored by hyperref.

Could you try to create your own [template](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#templates) (`pandoc -D beamer > mytemplate.tex`) without the `ignorenonframetext` and see whether that works without any adverse side effects? (When manually testing the .tex I always had to run LaTeX twice for the changes to take full effect.)

Comment: Thanks! I have used the new template, and now the link is there, but it is sending me to the first slide of the presentation, not to the "Section One" slide...

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Hyperlinks - at the bottom of the page, there are troubleshooting notes with beamer... basically, it seems that using hypertarget and hyperlink is required. Do you know how can this be achieved?

Comment: are you sure the posted TeX was generated from the posted Markdown? Look out for the `\hyperdef{}{part-one}` parts, those are the link targets.

Comment: I have updated the LaTex file just in case above in the question. Basically, when I replace by hand `\hyperref[section-one]{Section One}` to `\hyperlink{section-one}{Section One}`, it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm no LaTeX guru (usually I use ConTeXt myself), but I think it should work with `\hyperref` pointing to `\hyperdef` as well... but maybe you should bring up the issue on [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss) or their GitHub repo, or tex.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

Internal links do work, as long as they point to slides (not sections).  So the following should work:

```
# Part One {#part-one}

## Section One {#section-one} 

### Frame one {#frame-one}

- Items... 

### Frame two {#frame-two}

- Items... 
- Link to [Section One](#frame-one)
```

Of course, this workaround links to the first page of the section, so (1) one has to be careful when adding slides to the beginning of the section and (2) it does not work if the section has an automatic section page to which you want to link.  In that case, I see two options:

1. If you only want to link to the current or next sections start page, you can use `\hyperlinksectionstart{text}` and `\hyperlinksectionstartnext{text}` (which seem to be undocumented in the `beameruserguide`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233408/how-to-hyperlink-to-section-title-frame).
2. Create section pages manually and give them labels.